# Reading Files in Ruby

Tags: ruby

So, I'm relatively new to programming, and I have started working with ruby. I am going through "Learn how to code the hard way: Ruby" and I am on exercise 15; the beginning of file reading. I have copied the code they provided word for word, literally copy and pasted it to make sure, but I am getting the same error. I've googled the error, but to no avail. I have the .rb file in the same directory as the .txt file I'm trying to read. Here is my code.

```
filename = ARGV.first

prompt = "> "
txt = File.open(filename)

puts "Here's your file: #{filename}"
puts txt.read()

puts "I'll also ask you to type it again:"
print prompt
file_again = STDIN.gets.chomp()

txt_again = File.open(file_again)

puts txt_again.read()
```

The error I keep getting it this:

```
ex15.rb:19:in 'initialize': No such file of directory - ex15.txt <Errno::ENOENT>
from ex15.rb:4:in 'open'
from ex15.rb:4:in '<main>'
```

command to run it:

```
ruby ex15.rb ex15.txt
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: Does the file `ex15.txt` exist?

Comment: BTW you are not closing the handle to the files, which does not seem to be a good programming practice, you should have `txt.close` and `txt_again.close` somewhere at the end of your script

Comment: I'm running it like they had suggested, through cmd (in the directory where both the .rb file and .txt file exist)     ruby ex15.rb ex15.txt

Comment: Can you also add the command you run in the terminal and any input you type in? plus a listing of the files in your current directory?

Comment: Is your error accurate? I ask because you appear to have made a typo in it, which might mean it’s not entirely true to your case.

Comment: This works when I run it.  Are you sure you're executing it from the same folder that ex15.txt is in?

Comment: Is it just txt.close() and txt_again.close()?

Comment: Like @SomeGuy I tried this and it works. The problem is probably with the name of the text file. If the file exists you should be able to use the command `more ex15.txt` and see the contents of the file. If you get an error then it is most likely that the file has been created with a different name. It probably has spaces or other unexpected characters in the filename.

Answer (score 3):

When you don't specify the mode argument for File.open(), the default is 'r', which stands for `read`.  And to read a file, it has to exist already. The error message is telling you that there is no file named 'ex15.txt' in the current directory for ruby to read.

To get rid of the error, create a file called ex15.txt in the current directory, and type 'hello world' in the file.